# Interchange Axes in Collabion Charts for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, fusioncharts

I'm super new to Collabion Charts. With that being said, is there a way to swap axes for any chart?

For example I don't want a Column Chart to be a Bar chart. I just want the axes to be interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to swap the axes using Collabion charts.